# Share _Layout via reusable dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

Can I share _Layout.cshtml (MasterPage) in separate dll. I am using MvcContrib library for sharing Controllers/Views but do not know how to share _Layout.

MvcContrib approach is prefferable

Comment: You can create a NuGet package and have it copy to Views folder.

Comment: It should be possible, as you can pack ascx controls to dll. Refer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2005/10/31/turning-an-ascx-user-control-into-a-redistributable-custom-control.aspx

Comment: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/